# Maven llibrary and executable jar

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot

У меня есть Spring-boot приложение, которое собирается мавеном.

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/>
</parent>
...
<packaging>jar</packaging>
...
<build>
    <finalName>${finalName}</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

После сборки получается jar-пакет состава:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и его нельзя подтянуть в другой проект как либу...

а должно получиться:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

чтоб каталоги с классами лежали в корне архива.

Как настроить мавен так, чтоб при сборке приложения создавалась еще и библиотека из него?

Answer (score 3):

Ваше приложение собралось корректным образом, но раз вы задаете такой вопрос, то мне кажется, что у вас имеются некоторые проблемы с пониманием принципа работы SpringBoot starter'а.

**Подключение SpringBoot starter'а:**

После подключения `spring-boot-maven-plugin` в maven `pom.xml`, плагин автоматически подвяжется на goal `spring-boot:repackage`, которая запускается на maven phase `package`, поэтому все должно произойти автоматически при запуске команды `mvn package`.

Подробнее смотрите [здесь](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/build-tool-plugins.html).

**Как работает SpringBoot starter:**

Ваше приложение собирается полностью корректно, просто дело в том, что оно запускается не совсем так, как об этом думаете вы, поясню:

**Сборка:**

В результате работы maven phase `package` SpringBoot starter (`mvn package`):

1. maven собирает ваш проект и упаковывает его в .jar-файл (например, `my.jar`);
2. в подключенном `spring-boot-maven-plugin` срабатывает goal `repackage`:

   1. переименовывается созданный в п.1 jar-файл в `jar.original` (например, `my.jar.original`);
   2. снова создается jar-файл с оригинальным именем (например, `my.jar`):

      1. ваши maven dependency (из `pom.xml`) складываются в него (в `BOOT-INF/lib`);
      2. ваши классы из `jar.original` также складываются в него (в `BOOT-INF/classes`);
      3. служебные классы самого SpringBoot starter'а складываются в корень jar'ника (с учетом java package их размещения);
3. все ваши зависимости складываются в каталог `BOOT-INF/lib` итогового jar'ника;
4. все ваши скомпилированные классы складываются в каталог `BOOT-INF/classes` итогового jar'ника;
5. все свои скомпилированные классы складываются в корневой каталог итогового jar'ника (`org/springframework/boot/loader`);
6. в файле `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` в качестве основного класса (класса для запуска метода `public static void main(String[] args)`) указывается специальный класс SpringBoot'а (`org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher`), а не ваш (вопреки вашим ожиданиям), а информация о ваших классах указывается в других property этого файла:

Пример содержимого файла `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Implementation-Title: spring-boot
Implementation-Version: <версия_вашего_приложения> (например, 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT)
Start-Class: <fully_qualified_name_вашего_стартового_класса> (например, com.test.my.Application)
Spring-Boot-Classes: BOOT-INF/classes/ (сюда попадут ваши классы)
Spring-Boot-Lib: BOOT-INF/lib/ (сюда попадут ваши maven dependency)
Build-Jdk-Spec: 1.8
Spring-Boot-Version: 2.2.2.RELEASE
Created-By: Maven Archiver 3.4.0
Main-Class: org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher
```

**Запуск:**

В результате запуска исполняемого jar'ника (`java -jar <имя_вашего_jar'ника>`), получившегося в результате сборки (см. предыдущий пункт) происходит следующее:

1. согласно property `Main-Class` из `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` запускается main method специально класса SpringBoot starter'а: `org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher#main`;
2. этот класс (`org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher#main`):

   1. выполняет некоторую предварительную подготовку приложения к запуску;
   2. получает информацию о вашем приложении из `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` (см. выше):

      1. `Spring-Boot-Lib` - путь размещения используемых вами библиотек (maven dependency);
      2. `Spring-Boot-Classes` - ClassPath ваших классов;
      3. `Start-Class` - [fully-qualified name](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html) вашего стартового класса, содержащего метод main;
   3. посредством рефлексии (см. `org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner`) вызываем метод `main` вашего стартового класса.

**Проверка работы вашего приложения:** (после запуска)

Если в вашем приложении имеется хотя бы один `RestController`, то для того, чтобы удостовериться в том, что приложение корректно поднялось и работает следует его вызвать.

Рассмотрим на следующем примере:

1.приложение поднимается на порту `8080` (default'ное поведение без явного изменения настроек).

2.имеем следующий `RestController`:

```
@RestController
public class HelloWorldController {
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String helloWorld() {
        return "Hello world!";
    }
}
```

Вызываем метод `helloWorld`, например, одним из следующих образов:

1. указываем в окне браузера url `localhost:8080`;
2. используем консольную утилиту `curl`, т.е. в командной строке: `curl localhost:8080`;
3. используем какое-нибудь приложение (например, *Postman* или *SoapUI*).

Comment: Я дополнил свой комментарий.

Comment: @VitalyM., кажется я понял, что вам непонятно и постарался раскрыть этот момент в рамках ответа (точнее, в рамках update'а к нему).

Comment: спасибо за ответ. Но я не про то спрашиваю, хотя некоторые подробности мне были интересны. У меня все так и собирается и запускается. Проблема в том, что собранное spring-boot'ом приложение, не получается подтянуть в другой проект как библиотеку... У меня вопрос - можно-ли настроить мавен так, чтоб при сборке создавалось 2 jar'ника - 1 спринг-бутовский и 1 как библиотека?

Comment: @Vitaly M., при сборке jar'ника в пару к нему также собирается original jar: <наименование>.jar.original. Я так понимаю, он вас интересует? Подробности можно найти [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43641664/why-spring-boot-generates-jar-or-war-file-with-original-extension).

Comment: Разрулил профилями в мавене.

Comment: @VitalyM., я правильно понимаю, что вы сделали второй профиль maven, который просто не подключается spring-boot-maven-plugin?
По вашему контексту вопроса казалось, что вы хотите за одну сборку делать и то и то, а тут получается, что вы будете выполнять две сборки.

Comment: Да, все верно. У меня первоначальная задача так и стояла. Но потом мы с девопсом накурили еще один ci темплейт и получили возможность два раза прогонять сборку мавеном. А по поводу ориджинал, я вначале смотрел, он у меня был такой же как и основной. Нужно будет еще раз посмотреть.